# assert() function throwing an error something wrong with the operator

Tags: c++

The error I'm getting is

```
whole.cpp(384): error C2270: '==' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
whole.cpp(384): error C2805: binary 'operator ==' has too few parameters
whole.cpp(384): error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
```

I can't seem to pin down the problem though so here is the code

this is the operator implementation in the class 
     `bool operator==(const DateC& p) const{return ( DateC::DateC()== p.DateC() );};`

```
#include <assert.h>
int main(unsigned int argc, char* argv[])
{


DateC f(29,33,11);

DateC::testAdvancesWrap();
};

void DateC::testAdvancesWrap(void)
{
DateC d;
cout << "DateC::testAdvanceWrap()" << endl ;
cout << "*********************" << endl << endl ;
cout << "\tCHECK ADVANCE MULTIPLES:" << endl;
cout << "\t------------------------" << endl;
d.setDay(1);
d.setMonth(12);
d.setYear(1999); 
prettyPrint(d);
cout << "ACTION: set date 01-Dec-1999, advance, 31 days, 1 month and 1 year ->" << endl;
d.advance(1,1,31);

assert( d == DateC(1,2,2001) );

cout << "SUCCESS" << endl;

prettyPrint(d);
cout << endl << endl;
}
```

the rest of the functions working fine it's only the `assert()`

Comment: Does `DateC` have an `operator==` for itself?

Comment: what do you mean an operator for its self??explain

Comment: @amaressa RichiHindle means, is the == operator defined for the DateC class? Edit: The == operator is the equivalence operator that YOU must define for arbitrary classes. It will test to see if one object is equivalent to the other.

Comment: you have to define the operator for a custom class

Comment: sorry don't know what you mean show me an example

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong. You are using == to compare two DateC objects but never told the compiler how to do it.

Comment: @amaressa look here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading , you need to define == operator for for DateC object

Comment: well how do I tell the computer how to compare them then ?? show me some code

Comment: @amaressa search for an answer now you know what it's called, there are lots of examples out there.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your own classes, if you want to compare them, you need to create operators for them. Let's say you would like to compare 2 instances of a class Person.

A person consist of  a string and an int - lastname and height.

We wish to compare people by their height, so we need to tell the compiler how to do it.
An example:

```
class Person
{
    string lastname;
    int height;

    bool operator == (const Person& p) const
    {
        return (this->height == p.height);
    }

};
```

EDIT:

I think you misunderstood my example, you can only compare things that the compiler knows how to compare. Your Date implemantation probably has ints, so if you are checking for equality, you have to check all fields.

Use `this->` to have access to the other object's fields in the function.

Comment: @amaressa here is a little tutorial with a operator table:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/

Comment: You should probably make that operator `const`, and pass by `const` reference, since you don't need to copy the argument and a call to the operator shouldn't modify either operand.

Comment: You need the operator to be `const`, not the return value.

Comment: bool operator==(const DateC& p) const{return (p ==             DateC::DateC   ());};

Comment: 1>whole.cpp(384): error C2270: '==' : modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
1>whole.cpp(384): error C2805: binary 'operator ==' has too few parameters
=========